# Pyinstaller NotImplementedError can't perform this operation

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to turn my pthon code into an excutable in window using pyinstaller. 
But unforunately it keeps giving me the following error:

> NotImplementedError can't perform this operation

So I did a research to find out how to solve this issue. In [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1898) I could find out that one of my package that has dependancy of jinja2 was causing the issue ("folium in this case"). And one of the user named ***bjones1*** even said how to do simple workaround.

> > However, a simple workaround is to exclude the package containing Jinja2 templates from PyInstaller, then use datas = collect_data_files('template_package', None, True) in a hook file (or manually copy the package). I've attached my working example (but used the manual copy process): jinja2.zip.

Now, the problem is I'm fairly new to the Pyinstaller so I didn't really understand what he was talking about. So I did the more research and figured out how to include hook file + exclude packages. But I'm still not sure how to resolve this issue. So my question is this, how should I apply this into my situation so that when I try to import folium it doesn't give me any error.

FYI:
I'm using python 3.6 window7 and
here is the list of packages I imported in case anyone wonder.

```
import folium
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
import os
import engine                           # this is just self-made module that helps to run my code
import mplleaflet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import io 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
import math
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really take credit for this answer but it ended up working for me and I noticed this is the same core problem that you are experiencing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55982529/9431874

The part that messed me up is that I was modifying the package files in the Python36-32 folder rather than just the Python36 folder. Hopefully this works for you as well.