# pyinstaller unable to create .exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, folium

I'm trying to create a `.exe` file from my `python-folium` script (using `pyinstaller`).
Somehow it doesn't create the `.exe` file when executing `pyinstaller`.

After some googling, most of solution similar with
[Branca Python module is unable to find 2 essential json files when running an executable that uses folium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836440/branca-python-module-is-unable-to-find-2-essential-json-files-when-running-an-ex)

But somehow i get this error, with that solution:

```
4526 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec

Unable to find "venv\Lib\site-packages\branca\*.json" when adding binary and data files.
```

Any advice?

this my .spec file

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\my\\py\\system'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[
         (".\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\*.json","branca"),
         (".\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\templates","templates"),
         (".\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\folium\\templates","templates"),
         ],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='main',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the period `.` before the path of each file, check out their [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

You also only need one backslash `\`. Their documentation uses a forwardslash `/` in their examples however either type of slash `\` or `/` works fine and even double slashes `\\` work, I've tested them all out.

Try the following settings:

```
datas=[
("\venv\Lib\site-packages\branca\*.json", "branca"),
("\venv\Lib\site-packages\branca\templates", "templates"),
("\venv\Lib\site-packages\folium\templates", "templates"),
],
```

Comment: thank you Andrew Stone, it still not working, but you give me idea to change the address to full path address (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\branca\). and it's work. thank you

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help